# ffmpeg scale image with unrelated number in the name

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to scale image(s) that have any given name. I've found my script is failing on files that have numbers in the name. "0% financing", "24 Hour", etc. The other files are working fine, so it's not the script itself. I get:

> [image2 @ 0x7fbce2008000] Could find no file with path '/path/to/0% image.jpeg' and index in the range 0-4

How can I tell ffmpeg that this isn't a search pattern, or sequential numbered files ? There's only 1 jpeg in each location, and I do not have control of the file names to change them.

-update-
I've figured out the command

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type none -i /path/to/0%\ image/0%\ image.jpeg -vf scale=320:-1 /path/to/0%\ image/0%\ image.out.jpeg
```

gets me past the initial problem, but the output won't work because I can't get it now to escape the final argument. If I am in the directory (so no path) and change the output to just out.jpeg it will work, so I'm confident the first error is corrected.

Now I need to figure out how to use spaces in the path in the output argument? I've tried surrounding it in quotes:

```
"0% image.out.jpeg"
```

regular escapes:

```
0%\ image.out.jpeg
```

and surrounding it in quotes and using escapes at the same time:

```
"0%\ image.out.jpeg"
```

Comment: You should show your script.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I put the command that I'm using in. I'm running it in the terminal, and it's failing

Comment: I ended up using imagemagick convert for this, but I still never figured out the answer.